# fix oracle 11.2 asm performances (bad disks repartition)

Tags: oracle, storage

i've a single Oracle 11.2 node with really bad performances and i figure out that there's a lun always running at 100% IO.

This is the "DATA_0000" lun configured in asm in this way

---

SQL> SELECT name, header_status, path FROM V$ASM_DISK;

NAME                           HEADER_STATU

---

### PATH

DATA_0000                      MEMBER
/dev/dm-6

INDICI_0000                    MEMBER
/dev/dm-7

---

I'm not a dba at all, but i think this is  a really bad configuration causing bad performances. I'm planning to add 2 more luns (same size and storage enclosure as the originals) but i would like to know if is it possibile (without loosing data) to split existing luns between both VG

---

AS IS

dm-6 => DATA_0000 => DATA   500gb

dm-7 => INDICI_0000 => INDICI   500gb

To BE

dm-6    => DATA_0000
        => INDICI_0001

dm-7    => DATA_0001
        => INDICI_0000

---

Any help would be welcome.
Regards

Comment: to me it's not clear what the "To BE" is...anyway what you can do is: add 2 asmdisk from OS (/etc/init.d/oracleasm add ..),  add this 2 ASM disk to the same ASM DISKGROUP (via sqlplus: alter diskgroup XX add disk...). At that point, ASM itself wil spread data in all asmdisk. You can check with select like this: select GROUP_NUMBER,DISK_NUMBER,FREE_MB,NAME from v$asm_disk

Comment: Really thanks for your answer. I'm planning to add two more luns but i would like to know if its possibile to spread existing ams disks on both diskgroup DATA and INDICI. 
Thanks

Comment: No you can't. An asm disk can be assigned to only one ASM diskgroup.